# How do I fit a image in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fit this image in the bootstrap carousel. But it won't fit. What am I missing here? Any suggestions, please?

Screenshot:
[image]

Now, this is my CSS code here:

```
/* Carousel */
.carousel {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel .item {
    height: 300px;
}

.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Without your HTML, it will be hard to see, but it's most likely because you are using `position: absolute` for your image - and since that takes the element out of document flow and matches it to nearest parent with a `position` set, you might want to try adding `position: relative` to the `carousel-item` element OR not using `position: absolute` on your `img`. Again, it's hard to tell without your HTML.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score -1):

**You need to share your HTML for better solution.** You can use the class `img-fluid` on your img element. This will help apply a full width of the container with height of auto.